# Share a msg selectively with a worker in rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I want to define a queue such that all msgs coming to it is routed to different worker and at the same time shared specifically with one of the workers
I guess a diagram can explain better

W(i) - Worker which recieves distinct msgs

W(sp) - is special worker which recieves all the msgs

Q - Queue

'---------------------------------------Q-------------------------

|--------------------------- |---------------------------- |
 |--------------------------- |---------------------------- |
W1,W(sp)-------------W2,W(sp)-----------W3,W(sp)

As you can see W1,W2,W3,W4 are all distinct workers each receiving distinct msgs like a normal worker. Each will recieve one job from the queue

However each of the msgs should be shared with like an exchange W(sp).
How can i achieve it. Is there some parameter which i can set so that W(sp) can always receive all the events from the queue

It will be great if you could help

**EDIT 1**

I found its a little tricky to understand the question ,here's another version

I want to share jobs  from queue in round robin so that a job is given only once to a consumer as i want to do parallel processing of job, and at the same time i want a special consumer which will also get all the jobs from queue.

Eg:

counsumer - C1,C2,C3,C4

special consumer - Csp

queue - Q

Each job in Q should be broadcasted to one of C1,C2,C3,C4 and shared with Csp .
Thus a job from Q is shared between Csp and one of C(i). With this i will we able to parallely process jobs in C1,C2,C3,C4 etc and at the same time validate each of the jobs in Q with my consumer Csp

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need a [Topic Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html). Set up different routing keys for messages. And let Workers pick what they are interested in. For example, the worker that needs to get all messages can create a queue and bind it to the exchange with "#" (hash) binding key.

> > We created three bindings: Q1 is bound with binding key "*.orange.*" and Q2 with "*.*.rabbit" and "lazy.#".
>
> These bindings can be summarised as:
>
> ```
> Q1 is interested in all the orange animals.
> Q2 wants to hear everything about rabbits, and everything about lazy animals.
> ```
>
> A message with a routing key set to "quick.orange.rabbit" will be
>   delivered to both queues. Message "lazy.orange.elephant" also will go
>   to both of them. On the other hand "quick.orange.fox" will only go to
>   the first queue, and "lazy.brown.fox" only to the second.
>   "lazy.pink.rabbit" will be delivered to the second queue only once,
>   even though it matches two bindings. "quick.brown.fox" doesn't match
>   any binding so it will be discarded.

## UPDATED:

Take a look at the repositories that this guy has: https://github.com/simonmacmullen

I guess you will be interested in this one: https://github.com/simonmacmullen/random-exchange

```
This exchange type is for load-balancing among consumers.
```

Comment: Thnks for the reply Vor, however i see a problem.
Using topic broadcasts same msg to all consumers connected to that queue.
I want to share jobs in round robin so that a job is given only once to a consumer as i want to do parallel processing of job, and at the same time i want a special consumer which will also get all the jobs from queue.
Eg:
counsumer - C1,C2,C3,C4
special consumer - Csp
queue - Q
Each job should be broadcasted to one of C1,C2,C3,C4 and Csp
Thus msg is shared betweenn Csp and one of C(i)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vor for help but i guess that didnt help,
however i did solve the problem. 
It was just about givin the queue a name , so that all the consumers connected to queue will get the work shared in round robin.
Heres an example

counsumer - C1,C2,C3,C4

special consumer - Csp

queue - Q

I should create the connection as follows

Emit:

```
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs2',type='fanout')
```

For recieving events from C(i) i should bind my queue to exchange with a queue name

```
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs2',queue='hello')
```

Any Amount of Consumers connected to this queue will recieve one job at a time in round robin

For recieving events from exchange with Csp

```
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs2',queue='special')
```

This special queue will recieve all the events from the exchange as this is connected to exchange logs2